# erase value function for a double linked list, unknown error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linked-list

I'm getting the following error:

```
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(390): error C2664: 'int remove(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'DoubleLinkedList<int>::iterator' to 'const char *'
```

Here is the instance where the error pops up.

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::eraseVal(const T& value) {
    iterator it = begin();
    while ((it = std::find(it, end(), value)) != end()) { it = std::remove(it); }
}
```

More specifically, the error is coming from this line:

```
while ((it = std::find(it, end(), value)) != end()) { it = std::remove(it); }
```

Does anyone know how to approach this problem? The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/wwolfgang11).

Comment: It looks like you are picking up the runtime function remove from C. Do you have an include stdio.h/cstdio in your c++ code? You should remove it and use iostream instead (pun not intended)

Comment: @Anders I used iostream, algorithm, memory, utility, stdexcept, iosfwd, type_traits, and ostream.

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` in your header file?  If you do, get rid of it.  Are you using weird macros that add nothing except maybe you typing a few less letters?  Get rid of those.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], people shouldn't have to ask or follow links in order to find the relevant code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No I do not have using namespace std.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt My apologies, I am still a newb with this stuff.

Comment: Your class has `erase` method taking an iterator. I suspect you want to call that, in place of `std::remove` (which makes absolutely no sense here).

Comment: Oh, in that case, take the [tour] and check out [ask]. For this particular case, also read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) correctly.  You are supposed to provide two iterators, not one iterator to remove an element.

What is happening is that the compiler believes you are attempting to call [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) from `<cstdio>` that takes a character pointer, thus the error.

To fix the error, call `std::remove` with two iterator arguments.  The second argument denotes one element past the one you want to delete:

```
std::remove(it, std::next(it));
```

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: 'remove': function does not take 2 argument. I am not sure why I am getting this when I do not have an #include <stdio.h> anywhere

Comment: The documentation at the link explains how to fix the issue. The range of elements are from `[first, last)`.  Note the parenthesis on the right -- it has a special meaning.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx -- We have no idea what your code consists of.  It is obvious that function declaration is included somewhere, else the compiler would not have given the error.

Comment: Yea I am not seeing it, could it be possible that a library I am including contains stdio?

Comment: You could have been a victim of the [qualified name lookup rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup).